# For Firebase Simple Login, I have to login twice for it to register

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm pretty sure this is a problem of me not fully understanding asynchronous javascript, but I'll explain my problem.

I have an email/password authenticated with Firebase, and I have a login page with the following form:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" action="#" onsubmit="return login(this);">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please log in</h2>
    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
```

When I click the button I get the following error in my JS console that flashes really quickly:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined --- firebase-simple-login.js:132

At the bottom of my head tag I include the script "js/firebase.js" and this is that file:

```
var myRef = new Firebase("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com");

var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(myRef, function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else if (user) {
    console.log("User ID: " + user.uid + ", Provider: " + user.provider);
  } else {
  }
});

function login(form)
{
    auth.login('password', {
      email: form.email.value,
      password: form.password.value
    });
}
```

After I fill out the form, press the button and get the error, the fields go blank and there is a "?#" appended to the end of my URL. If I try to login after this it works perfectly. Thanks in advance!

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first time you load this page and click "login" your form is being submitted and the page is reloading, preventing simple login from successfully completing. See [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms).